# Change color of absolutely positioned element when overlapping with another

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to build a component where you can visualize on what section are you in and allows you to easily move sections on the page.

My page is structured like this

```
<SectionManager /> // the absolutely positioned element
<Navbar />
<Menu />
<Section1 />
<Section2 />
<Section3 />
{...}
```

I want to have every even numbered section to have a black background and the others to have a white background. Now I want the text inside my `SectionManager` component to be white when overlapping a black background and black when overlapping a white background.

Here is a photo:
[image]

My component is the one on the left. And when you scroll down to the black section I want just the `about me` text and the circle after that to turn white.

Sorry if this is a stupid question by I searched for hours and did not find anything. I tried `mix-blend-mode` but it did not work.

Here the code for my component:

```
const SectionManager: React.FC = () => {
  const globalState = React.useContext(MyContext);

  const observerCallback = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    ...
  };

  const observerOptions = React.useMemo(
    ...
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(...);
    globalState.currentSections.forEach((section: HTMLElement) => {
      observer.observe(section);
    });
  }, []);

  const sections = [
    {
      text: "Hello!",
    },
    {
      text: "about me",
    },
    {
      text: "work i did",
    },
    {
      text: "contact",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={styles.sectionManager}>
      {sections.map((section, sectionID) => (
        <>
          {sectionID > 0 && (
            <div className={styles.sectionManager_separator}></div>
          )}
          <div
            className={
              sectionID === globalState.activeSectionId
                ? `${styles.sectionManager_item} ${styles.sectionManager_itemActive}`
                : styles.sectionManager_item
            }
          >
            <p>{section.text}</p>
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionManager;
```

here is the scss file:

```
.sectionManager {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  &_separator {
    width: 1px;
    height: 25px;
    background: $text-secondary-dark;
    margin-right: 7px;
  }

  &_itemActive {
    &::after {
      background-color: $text-primary-light !important;
      transform: scale(1) !important;
    }

    p {
      color: $text-primary-light !important;
      transform: scaleX(1) !important;
    }
  }

  &_item {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    @include transition();

    &:hover {
      &::after {
        background-color: $text-primary-light;
        transform: scale(1);
      }

      p {
        transform: scaleX(1);
        color: $text-primary-light;
      }
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transform-origin: right;
      color: $text-secondary-light;
      @include transition();
    }

    &::after {
      content: "";
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 999999px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      transform: scale(0.9);
      background: $text-secondary-dark;
      @include transition();
    }
  }
}
```

And for the section background I am not doing anything fancy, I am just setting a `background-color` property on there.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
[image]

I want something similar to that. The design is in figma.

Comment: DId you try white text with mix-blend-mode difference?

Comment: @AHaworth yes I did, and it does not work.

Comment: Could you show us that try as I can get white on black and black on white with a simple layout.

Comment: @AHaworth You managed to get white on black and black on white?

Comment: maybe intersection observer will work?

Comment: @KunalTanwar Yes I will try that, i will get all the sections using querySelector, get the section that is in view and get it's background color, and reverse it in sass.

Comment: @Meriegg yes - white on black difference gives white of course and white on white gives black (as there is no difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue!

I ended up getting all the sections on my page using `querySelector` and using an `IntersectionObserver` to get the section that is in viewPort and get its background color, then passing the background color to my component using `data-section-bg`.

Here is the whole component code:

```
const SectionManager: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentSectionBg, setCurrentSectionsBg] =
    React.useState<string>("#fff");
  const globalState = React.useContext(MyContext);

  const observerCallback = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    // other observer ...
  };

  const sectionColorObserverCallback = (
    entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]
  ) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.25) {
        const sectionBgColor = (
          document.getElementById(entry.target.id) as HTMLElement
        ).style.backgroundColor;
        console.log(sectionBgColor);

        setCurrentSectionsBg(sectionBgColor);
      }
    });
  };

  const observerOptions = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 0.25,
    }),
    []
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    // other observer...
    );
    globalState.currentSections.forEach((section: HTMLElement) => {
      // other observer...
    });
    
    // Detect Section Color Observer
    const allSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    if (!allSections) return;

    const sectionColorObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
      sectionColorObserverCallback,
      observerOptions
    );
    allSections.forEach((section, sectionId) => {
      section.id = `SECTION_${sectionId}`;
      section.style.backgroundColor = sectionId % 2 === 0 ? "#fff" : "#000";

      sectionColorObserver.observe(section);
    });
  }, []);

  const sections = [
    {
      text: "Hello!",
    },
    {
      text: "about me",
    },
    {
      text: "work i did",
    },
    {
      text: "contact",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ x: 150, opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{
        x: 0,
        y: "-50%",
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
          duration: 1,
          delay: 0.8,
          ease: defaultAnimationEasing,
        },
      }}
      className={styles.sectionManager}
    >
      {sections.map((section, sectionID) => (
        <>
          {sectionID > 0 && (
            <div className={styles.sectionManager_separator}></div>
          )}
          <div
            data-section-bg={currentSectionBg}
            className={
              sectionID === globalState.activeSectionId
                ? `${styles.sectionManager_item} ${styles.sectionManager_itemActive}`
                : styles.sectionManager_item
            }
          >
            <p>{section.text}</p>
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default SectionManager;
```

Here is what I added to my scss File:

```
[data-section-bg="rgb(0, 0, 0)"] {
    &:hover {
      &::after {
        background: $text-primary-dark !important;
      }

      p {
        color: $text-primary-dark;
      }
    }

    p {
      color: $text-primary-dark;
    }
  }

  [data-section-bg="rgb(255, 255, 255)"] {
    &:hover {
      &::after {
        background: $text-primary-light !important;
      }

      p {
        color: $text-primary-light;
      }
    }

    p {
      color: $text-primary-light;
    }
  }

  &_itemActive[data-section-bg="rgb(255, 255, 255)"] {
    &::after {
      background-color: $text-primary-light !important;
    }
  }

  &_itemActive[data-section-bg="rgb(0, 0, 0)"] {
    &::after {
      background-color: $text-primary-dark !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: that's great 